# Get the day of a month with the week day and year

Tags: php

I have the year, the week day, the week and the month, I'd like to return the day of the month.

I mean It returns me with dayweek, week, month and year:

```
$month = "September";
$year = "2013";
$dayWeek= "Friday";
$week = 2;
```

It returns the day of the month: it could be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide expected output, as well as some code indicating you've tried to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: The expected output would be the day of the month in number 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 etc etc @miken32

Comment: What do you mean by `$week = 2`? If a month starts on a Wednesday, is `$week = 1` from that Wednesday until the next Wednesday? Or is it until the next monday/sunday? Also, what is the first day of the week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
// your input
$month      = "September";
$year       = "2013";
$dayWeek    = "Friday";
$week       = 2;


// create a date object
$date = new DateTime();

// set to the first day of the specified year/month
$date->modify($year . '-' . $month . '-01');

// add $week -1 weeks to the date
$date->modify('+' . ($week - 1) . ' week');

// set to day of week
$date->modify($dayWeek);

// here's the day of month for you
echo $date->format('j');
```

returns `2013-09-13`

Comment: Make it a `$date->format('j');` and you might have what he's looking for

Comment: I did miss his comment there on the question. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cat try do it using `nesbot/carbot` package:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

...

switch($week) {
    case 1:
        $weekNumber = 'first';
        break;
    case 2:
        $weekNumber = 'second';
        break;
    case 3:
        $weekNumber = 'third';
        break;
    case 4:
        $weekNumber = 'fourth';
        break;
    default:
        $weekNumber = 'fifth';
}

// Now $date will be a Carbon\Carbon instance and $date->day will return day of month
$date = Carbon::parse(sprintf("%s %s of %s %s", $weekNumber, $dayWeek, $month, $year));
```